# How to Attach Tight Rigid Body Physics to Extruded SVG with React Three Rapier

Tags: svg, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei, rapier

> I've also asked [this on Three.js Discourse](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-attach-tight-rigid-body-physics-to-extruded-svg-with-react-three-rapier/59490).

I'm trying to get to a tight inferred mesh from [@react-three/rapier](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-rapier)'s `<RigidBody>` on an extruded SVG geometry, much like the `hull` example in [this CodeSandbox from their docs](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-three-rapier-auto-colliders-b4coz1?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx). However, so far, the best inferred shape I've got is a cuboid, and it also outpositions the collider.

When I try to apply a `hull` on it, here's the error I get:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'array')
```

Since this is a mesh of meshes, I think it gets lost? I don't know. Maybe I need something like an `<InstancedMesh>`? I have no idea. Sorry, I'm new to this physics thing.

Anyways, here's [a CodeSandbox based on that other one with the extruded SVG](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-three-rapier-auto-colliders-forked-6kvf7t?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A21%2C17&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwt1ia00063b6jglntqapz%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwt1ia00023b6jgntfiv8o%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwt1ia00033b6jht32erbk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwt1ia00053b6jje5d6h6l%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50.79312623925975%252C49.20687376074025%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqdwt1ia00023b6jgntfiv8o%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwt1ia00023b6jgntfiv8o%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clqdwt1ia00053b6jje5d6h6l%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwt1ia00043b6jlg3rzokh%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwt1ia00053b6jje5d6h6l%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqdwt1ia00043b6jlg3rzokh%2522%257D%252C%2522clqdwt1ia00033b6jht32erbk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqdwt1ia00033b6jht32erbk%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

And, for reference, here's the extruded SVG code:

```
import { useMemo } from "react";

import * as THREE from "three";
import { SVGLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/Addons.js";
import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";

type ExtrudedSvgProps = {
  filename: string;
  scale?: number;
  position?: [number, number, number];
};
export default function ExtrudedSvg({
  filename,
  scale = 1,
  position = [-10, 10, 0],
}: ExtrudedSvgProps) {
  const svgData = useLoader(SVGLoader, filename);
  const shapes = useMemo(() => {
    return svgData.paths.map((p) => p.toShapes(true));
  }, [svgData]);

  return (
    <mesh
      scale={scale}
      rotation={[Math.PI, 0, 0]}
      position={[position[0] + 5, position[1] - 2, position[2] + 2]}
    >
      {shapes.map((s, i) => (
        <mesh key={i} position={[0, 0, 0]}>
          <extrudeGeometry
            args={[
              s,
              {
                depth: 5,
                bevelEnabled: false,
                steps: 30,
              },
            ]}
          />
          <meshPhongMaterial
            attach="material"
            color={svgData.paths[i].color}
            side={THREE.DoubleSide}
          />
        </mesh>
      ))}
    </mesh>
  );
}
```

And here's how I'm using it:

```
<RigidBody colliders="cuboid" position={[-5, 20, 0]}>
  <ExtrudedSvg
    filename="fanaro.io.svg"
    scale={0.1}
    position={[-5, 10, 0]}
  />
</RigidBody>
```

Comment: Apparently, the solution is super simple. Just take out the outer `<mesh>`, and just return `<> {shapes.map(...)} </>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a set of `<mesh>`es inside a `<mesh>`, if you put them inside a fragment (`<></>`) or a `<group>`, it works:

```
<group>
  {shapes.map((s, i) => (
    <mesh ...>
      ...
    </mesh>
  ))}
</group>
```